# How to add a line to a bar chart

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, data-analysis

*Diclaimer: I am still pretty new to data analysis and Python, so if you see a better way to write code for plotting my data, I would be more than happy to get feedback.*

I have data for two different categories, over 7 weeks.
I need to plot this data onto a graph and make it easy to read.

The first thing I did it to create a bar chart with data from group 2 stacked on data from group 1. 
However I would also like to add a line to my graph that shows the evolution of the data from group 2 a little better.

But when I do so, the line seems to use different values for x, even though I used the exact same thing.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
sns.barplot('week', 'group1', data=memberships, color = '#E30613', saturation=1)
sns.barplot('week', 'group2', data=memberships, color = '#009FE3', bottom=group1, saturation=1)
sns.lineplot('week', 'group2', data=memberships)
```

[The result](https://ibb.co/fj40Sq)

What can I do to have the line on top of the bar chart?

EDIT: To complement my question, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHyxA.png) is the dataset I am using

Comment: I am surprised the line is not on top of the bar chart already since you specify the same x-values for the bar- and the lineplot. Could you post a few lines of the `membership` data?

Comment: I just edited the post, thank you for trying to help me out. Same as you I don't understand since I use the same x-values

Comment: a barplot is for categorical data, and uses sequential ordinal x-positions for each category (0,1,2,...).  But the *labels* (in your case) are numerical and not starting at zero.  seaborn doesn't allow specification of the x-positions in barplots. See https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html.  In the lineplot, the x-positions are defined by the first argument, i.e., `'week'`.

Comment: if it is essential to add these two types of plot on one figure, you might be better off using matplotlib. See https://python-graph-gallery.com/5-control-width-and-space-in-barplots/ for an example of how to set x positions in a bar plot. But perhaps you can just rethink how to show your data (e.g. [with 2 subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52970872/1643946))

Comment: Thank you for your help, using matplotlib instead of seabron seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled a lot with this one. First I tried to plot using the `plot` methods from pandas but I could not manage to get the line graph on top of the bar graph. So I used the standard matplotlib functions.

```
memberships = pd.DataFrame(data={'week':range(37,44), 
                                 'group1':[248, 243, 287, 354, 315, 348, 303], 
                                 'group2':[42,53,65,73,60,62,84]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(memberships.week-0.5, memberships.group1, color = '#E30613')
ax.bar(memberships.week-0.5, memberships.group2, color = '#009FE3', bottom=memberships.group1)
ax.plot(memberships.week, memberships.group2, linewidth=4)
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with that, than you very much! (I just removed the -0.5 you added to the weeks, because it looks better in my opinion)